# I found some misspelling in my Ubuntu calendar

Tags: language-support

My name is Mahdi Vojoudi and Im from Iran .When I choosed persian calendar for my Ubuntu I found some misspelling .I will be so happy if I can help Ubuntu developers 
to correct this .I can translate the words from english to persian for making Ubuntu better .

Comment: adding to Karel: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-fa  is where you Persians gather for translations ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to point out only a few mistakes in the Persian translation of the Calendar, filing a bug as karel suggest is the way.

I'm not sure, but I get the impression that you are interested in contributing to the Persian translation of Ubuntu beyond the Calendar. In that case I would recommend that you get in touch with the [Ubuntu Persian Translation Reviewers team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-fa). They should be able to give you the guidance you need to get started.

Comment: Did you just made a post on out 2 comments?  Have an upvote for the audacity! :D